# how to add a raw device on RHL

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, partition

I am using a server to which someone added a harddisk. I am struggling to get this to work. I am a regular Linux user (but haven't done this stuff before).

I have googled up and tried to follow the instructions and am stumped at the moment.

I used cfdisk to create a new partition

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           2         501      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2             502       30720    30944256   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3           30721       51200    20971520   83  Linux
```

/dev/sda3 was created as a result of that operation.

I tried to mount this  (shown below) and receive the message special device does not exist.

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /install
mount: special device /dev/sda3 does not exist
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: The operations you did look more like a disk that was resized, not a completely new disk as that would most likely appear as `/dev/sdb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

Linux only reads partition tables when disks are initially detected by the system (i.e. at boot time or when connected later). You can use the `partprobe` command to rescan the partition table on demand. N.B. On some distributions partprobe has problems with rescanning the partition table of the boot drive and a reboot may be required.

After creating a new *partition* you need create a file system, before you'll be able to mount it.

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3
```

Comment: THanks HBruijin Tried partprobe.As you mentioned there seems to be an error.Warning: WARNING: the kernel failed to re-read the partition table on /dev/sda (Device or resource busy).  As a result, it may not reflect all of your changes until after reboot.
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Error: Invalid partition table - recursive partition on /dev/sr0.

Comment: As suggested rebooted and it worked well. Many thanks

Comment: That is a bit strange that adding a hard drive resulted in a new partition.  If anything it should result in a new hard drive like /dev/sdb or something.  Did you make sure there is not another device added like /dev/sdb that you are supposed to use instead of adding the partition to the existing disk?  Just wondering.  If that's the case, it's possible that the hard drive was added but not seen until after you rebooted.  Check with "fdisk -l".

Comment: And if that's the case, you can usually do a rescan by going to /sys/class/scsi_host.  Here you will see directories of each host bus adapter in the system.  If you just have the one raid card, you will likely only see "host0".  You can cd to host0 and type in the command  echo "- - -" > host0/scan and it will rescan.  This is a normal practice with linux servers that have attached fiber and a new SAN disk is added and we want to rescan without reboot (i type more on that topic here: http://geekswing.com/geek/linux/lvm-on-linux-tutorial-adding-hard-drives-for-more-space/ )